# Select dinámico con laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en local y tengo una apartado de usuarios donde se registran. Entre los campos de registro tengo un `<select>` para los estados y otro para las ciudades. En mi base de datos tengo una tabla para estados, y otra para las ciudades, y están relacionadas de la siguiente forma: en la tabla ciudades tengo un campo estado_id porque las ciudades pertenecen a un estado. De esta forma sé que ciudades pertenecen a que estado.

¿Cómo podría hacer para que al seleccionar el estado, me muestre solo las ciudades que le pertenecen? Actualmente muestro todas las ciudades así como todos los estados y lo veo algo poco práctico, me gustaría mejorarlo de ese modo.

Select ESTADOS

```
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="estado" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado</label>

            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control" name="estado" id="estado">

                    @foreach ($estados as $estado)
                        <option value="{{$estado->id}}">{{$estado->nombre}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Select CIUDADES

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ciudad" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ciudad</label>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control" name="ciudad" id="ciudad">
                @foreach ($ciudades as $ciudad)
                    <option value="{{$ciudad->id}}">{{$ciudad->nombre}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

Acción del controlador que mando tanto las ciudades como los estados.

```
    public function create(){

    $estados = Estado::all();
    $ciudades = Ciudad::all();
    $puestos = Puesto::all();
    return view('users.create', [
        'estados' => $estados,
        'ciudades' => $ciudades,
        'puestos' => $puestos,
    ]);
}
```

Este es el `<select>` utilizado en la vista

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="ciudad" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ciudad</label>

       <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select name="ciudad" id="ciudad"></select>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Esta es la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este fue el codigo que probe

```
$("#ciudad").select2({
    placeholder: "Selecciona una opción",
    language: "es",
    width: '100%',
    ajax: {
        url: "{{ route('ciudad.select2') }}",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    templateResult: plantillaBusqueda,
    templateSelection: plantillaSeleccionado
});

function plantillaBusqueda(ciudad) {
    return ciudad.nombre;
}

function plantillaSeleccionado(ciudad) {
    if (ciudad.text != "") {
        return ciudad.text
    }
    return ciudad.nombre;
}
```

Mi ruta quedo tal que así

```
Route::get('ciudad/select2', 'HomeController@buscarLocalidad')->name('ciudad.select2');
```

y el HomeController quedo así

```
public function buscarLocalidad()
{
    $q       = trim(\request('q'));
    $results = Ciudad::where('nombre', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')->take(15)->get();

    return Response::json($results);
}
```

Peticion en el navegador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error 404 en navegador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Inspector de elementos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede hacer con peticiones AJAX refrescando los options del select, pero mi recomendación es que uses una librería llamada select2.

El javascript te quedaría tal que así

```
$("#ciudad").select2({
                        placeholder: "Selecciona una opción",
                        language: "es",
                        width: '100%',
                        ajax: {
                            url: "{{ route('ciudad.select2') }}",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            delay: 250,
                            data: function (params) {
                                return {
                                    q: params.term
                                };
                            },
                            processResults: function (data) {
                                return {
                                    results: data
                                };
                            },
                            cache: true
                        },
                        templateResult: plantillaBusqueda,
                        templateSelection: plantillaSeleccionado
                    });

function plantillaBusqueda(ciudad) {
            return ciudad.nombre;
        }

function plantillaSeleccionado(ciudad) {
        if (ciudad.text != "") {
            return ciudad.text
        }
        return ciudad.nombre;
    }
```

y tendrías que hacerte un método en el controlador para gestionarla:

```
Route::get('ciudad/select2', 'HomeController@buscarLocalidad')->name('ciudad.select2');


public function buscarLocalidad()
{
    $q       = trim(\request('q'));
    $results = Ciudad::where('nombre', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')->take(15)->get();

    return Response::json($results);
}
```

[DOCUMENTACION SELECT2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: Hola acabo de probarlo y sigue sin funcionar, puse el código tal como me mencionas el único cambio que hice fue en la ruta, que creo estaba errónea, ya que hiciste referencia al método buscar y era buscarLocalidad, aun con esa corrección me sigue sin arrojar ningún resultado. Edite la pregunta y agregue mi select en la vista.

Comment: Yo lo uso a diario y funciona, pon algo de lo que probaste. PD: efectivamente el buscar estaba mal

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, puse el código que probé y el resultado en la vista. Muchas gracias!

Comment: has mirado en el natevagor las peticiones que te hace al escribir en el select2?

Comment: No habia revisado, acabo de revisar, creo que debe ser la url en la consulta con ajax no? o tu que opinas. Adjunte un foto arriba en la pregunta.

Comment: Abre el inspector de elementos y ve a Network. Una vez allí escribe algo en el select2 y mira la petición que te hace (puedes hacerle click y darle a "open in new tab" y  así lo ves mejor)

Comment: Listo, puse imágenes en la pregunta, revisando mi controlador, me di cuenta que no estaba llamando el modelo de ciudad por lo tanto el `ciudad::where()` no estaba funcionando, ya lo agregue pensando que ese era el error pero sigue sin traerme nada el `select`

Comment: Estas viendo que no te traduce las url?

Comment: Si fue lo que te mencione arriba de la url, me podrías decir a que se debe? no encuentro la solución

Comment: Una disculpa, encontré mi error y termino funcionando! Gracias.